# asp.net custom handler exceptions?

Tags: asp.net

I have built a custom handler to threat requests of some specific files:

```
<add verb="*" path="*.pps,*.pdf,*.ppt,*.doc" type="CustomHandler"/>
```

Now, there is a folder, let's say: "/free/" where this handler should not be called. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a [remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0dzxdza.aspx) element inside a web.config in that folder.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
         <remove verb="*" path="*.pps,*.pdf,*.ppt,*.doc"/>
      </httpHandlers>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It perfectly works in FF but on Chrome it says: "Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data." Do you have any clue, why?:)

Comment: Try it in IE, Fiddler, and the Chrome Dev tools. This is more likely a configuration issue with something else being changed on IIS or the ASP.NET config if it is a server issue. Post your IIS and .NET versions too.